# How to solve nullpointerException?

Tags: android

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

this line of code is creating nullpointerException according to logcat, how to solve this ?

```
    package com.ftfl.ftflnavigationtab;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.ftfl.ftflnavigationtab.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener{

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "General Health", "Vaccination", "Growth Rate" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener((android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener) this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Post more code and stacktrace

Comment: This is nowhere near enough data to answer your question. Null pointer exceptions can be caused by a number of issues. First and foremost if I must guess: Check that actionBar is defined properly, in the proper scope and of the proper type.

Comment: i have added the full code

Comment: @najmulhasan: have you try it using `getSupportActionbar()` instead of `getActionBar()` ?

Comment: i have tried , but its suggesting me to create that method

Comment: @najmulhasan: ok then probably need to extends `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`

Comment: i have tried that too, still not working, i have edited the code

Comment: Device or emulator, on which Android version are you runing your application? (Android < 3 does not have any `ActionBar`)

Comment: i am using device, android version 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Debug which part of your code throws you the NullPointerException, and then, before it excecutes, you can validate that the object you're using it's not null.

If you're passing an object as a parameter, you can do this:

```
if(MyObject != null)
{
    DoOperation(MyObject);
}
```

If you're calling a method from a object:

```
if(MyObject != null)
{
    MyObject.myMethod();
}
```

Or you can also surround with a try/catch if you consider it's needed, but the best way to solve it it's to verify your objects before they are used.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `ActionBarActivity` as in:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
}
```

[Documentation advice:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)
Note: If you want to implement an activity that includes an action bar, you should instead use the ActionBarActivity class, which is a subclass of this one [`FragmentActivity`], so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and higher.

Edit:
Your `res/layout/styles.xml` may look like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

You then should remove the `.NoActionBar` or replace it with `.DarkActionBar` if you want the action bar to follow the dark theme.

Comment: @najmulhasan Edited, you should add your `res/layout/styles.xml` to your question if what I added didn't helped you so others  (or I) can help

Comment: i changed the theme in manifest file, but still same condition , and i dont understand that how  changing the theme will affect the nullpointerException?

Comment: The `NoActionBar` would tell the Activity it does not have an action bar so `actionbar = getActionBar()` would give you `null`. `actionbar` being null, `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);` would trigger a `NullPointerException` because it would try to call the method `setHomeButtonEnabled` on a `null` variable.

Comment: thanks for clearing , but i changed it, then why its still getting nullpointer?

Answer (score 0):

The NPE is happening the first time you access `actionBar` after assigning it with `getSupportActionBar()`, which means `getSupportActionBar()` is returning null. According to the documentation, it returns null when the current theme doesn't have an action bar.

Your manifest must declare a theme that supports the action bar, such as `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Put this inside the activity declaration in the manifest like this:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding

Comment: I have added the theme like theme.appcomcat.light.darkactionbar